# Desktop vs Mobile Angular 2 Load Times

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, performance, angular, load, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI to build a webpage with bootstrap version 4. I'm running into an issue with load times on mobile devices. On desktop it loads under a second. While on mobile it takes just over 10 seconds to load.

Same wifi, no cache or cookies on either system. Is this just because of the lack of processing power on mobile devices to handle all the js? Any ideas on how to improve load time??

Once the webpage is loaded, everything is very snappy. Consequence of using webpack I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AOT compiler. Otherwise (JIT) all the JS is loaded an compiled on the client-side!

Steps to improve:

- using AOT (including gzip, mini- and uglify) [anugular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)
- simplify modules
- lazy-load modules